# Is the word "overseas" only used to country bordered by water?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Can the word "overseas" be used to country bordered by land. For example is it correct if someone says I am doing work overseas if he is is doing work in the neighbouring country border by land not water with his country?

Comment: The [dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=overseas+definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=yw5MWZXxHNGw8wfh1aGIDQ) seem split on this: half say only "across the sea or ocean", and the other half say "in or relating to a foregn country _especially across water_.

Comment: It's beginning to be a "quaint" term regardless... a relic of the pre air-transportation era I would say.

Comment: It's vague. In the US, Mexico is not overseas, Guatemala is not overseas,... Panama, I'm not sure..., Columbia??? ... Brazil seems so far away, I'm sure it is overseas, Argentina is totally overseas..or maybe not. Iceland is overseas.It all depends and there wil always be fuzzy parts to it.

Comment: @Mitch I think the largest consensus is that anything south of the [Darién Gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari%C3%A9n_Gap) is overseas, because you generally have to go by sea or air to get across it (I suppose it might be possible to hack through on foot, but it sounds very iffy). So Panama is not "overseas" from the US but Colombia is. On the flipside, I would not consider Hawaii "overseas" from California, even though you obviously have to cross the Pacific ocean to get there. I'm now very curious whether Panama and Colombia would consider each other "overseas".

Comment: @1006a I don't think you got my point. It's vague. Do you have to take a boat or plane to Mexico? No. But aside from Tijuana and other border towns, that's probably what you'll do. Is Columbia overseas from Panama itself? Probably not. It ain't  all logic and 'does it pass this litmus test?', it's mostly vague feelings, mostly definite at the ends and a guess in the middle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent word for 'overseas' for a non-island country?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197741/equivalent-word-for-overseas-for-a-non-island-country)

Comment: @Mitch No, I got it, and I agree with it. What I meant by the "widest consensus" was that if you google "is south america overseas from the US" most answers say something like *Yes, because of the Darién Gap*.  The sentence about Panama and Colombia was meant as an illustration of that viewpoint. But, of course, the fact that people are asking the question means that the concept is confusing/vague, which is why I just referred to the consensus in a comment, rather than posting it as a rule in an answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - the question you suggest is related, they ask two different things,,,but you can't resist closevoting....

Comment: @Josh there are answers there. But you can't resist LMGTFYing.

Comment: @1006a excellent, sorry I misunderstood

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - it is not a duplicate, like it or not!

Comment: Why isn´t Guatemala overseas? When I fly to and from Miami and New York I am definitely crossing a large body of water, namely the Caribbean (or Mexican Gulf).

Comment: [Both Royal Mail in the UK and US Postal Service use "overseas" stamped packaging and envelopes for sending postage to another country. The mail services of all other European countries including the Russian Post use "abroad" stamped packaging and envelopes.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/239660/44619)

Answer (score 5):

From a British  English perspective it is a synonym of abroad, but from a continental Europe perspective, for instance, it would not be used to refer to countries that are not divided  by the sea or the ocean.

[Overseas](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overseas):

> to or in a foreign country, especially those separated from your country by the sea or ocean
>   (synonym abroad)
>
> - *to live/work/go overseas
>     The product is sold both at home and overseas.
>     He was working overseas for an oil company.*

(OLD)

[Overseas](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=overseas):

> - 1580s, from over + sea. *Popularised during World War I as a British euphemism for "colonial."*

(Etymonline)

Comment: Jay's answer at the-thread-where-this-has-already-been-addressed is 'The U.S. is not an island but we routinely refer to foreign countries as "overseas". People quibble about whether Canada and Mexico are "overseas" as you don't have to go over any seas to get there.' OP here could have looked up 'overseas' themself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - that's a comment, not an answer!!!

Comment: It illustrates that the original is indeed a duplicate, soliciting the type of answer given here. Why not post your answer there?